# How to read Json file in R?

Tags: json, r

I want to import my Json file in R.

```
install.packages("rjson")
library(rjson)
JsonData <- fromJSON(file="gistfile.json")
```

I used the above code to import the file. The file contains 100 records but the code imports only the first record. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I always prefer `library(jsonlite)`, I find it works more consistently. May be worth a try.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's best practice to provide a reproducible example - can you add a link to your file?

Comment: also, there are 3 packages that have a fromJSON function, as a safety precaution, I always explicitly state which package I'm using the function from. example: `jsonlite::fromJSON(file='gistfile.json')` it will save you a world of frustration later. (jsonlite is good, I also use RJSONIO)

Answer (score -1):

install and import library rjson

```
library("rjson")
prov_data <- fromJSON(*.json")
print(prov_data)
```